# How to intercept (block) SharePoint invitation

Tags: sharepoint-online, external-sharing

In SharePoint, you have the option (once enabled) to share a site with an external user. This external user will receive an invitation by e-mail, and will gain access once he or she accepts this invitation. After accepting this invitation, this user will be visible in the (for example) group you added them in.

I currently have a problem. One of our users invited an external user whom we planned to invite next week. Now I want to disable this user from accessing the site, but the user only shows up in the list after he accepts the invite. I can delete him them, but then it is too late, and I don't want to watch this list to see if he has accepted the invite.

I know I can disable external sharing or delete the group the user was invited for, however, there are numerous other people who already need access and have access via this group, which means I can't delete it.

**So:** I want to intercept (or block) an invite, so a user which received this invite is not able to accept it.

Does anybody know a way to achieve this, any help would be much appreciated!